# Der Unterschied zwischen »wegen«, »über« und »von« im Ausdruck »jemandem schreiben«

Tags: difference, preposition

> Ich schreibe meinem Freund wegen des Autounfalls.
>   Ich schreibe meinem Freund über den Autounfall.
>   Ich schreiben meinem Freund von dem Autounfall.

Ich möchte gern wissen, ob die folgenden Präpositionen oben ausgetauscht werden können. In Zeitungen habe ich schon gelesen, dass man öfters *wegen* statt *über* oder *von* schreibt. Ist *wegen* formeller als *über* und *von* zusammen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die drei Präpositionen beschreiben unterschiedliche Sachverhalte.

## Wegen

*Wegen* bezeichnet den Grund einer Handlung.

> Ich schreibe meinem Freund *wegen* des Autounfalls.

Dieser Satz bedeutet, dass der Autounfall der *Auslöser* des Schreibens ist. Vielleicht liege ich infolge des Unfalls im Krankenhaus und möchte noch schnell etwas loswerden. Vielleicht ist mein Freund auch mein Versicherungsberater und muss sich nun um den Schaden kümmern. Auf jeden Fall ist der Autounfall die Ursache, das Schreiben die Wirkung davon.

Es ist nicht gesagt, dass der Inhalt des Briefes den Autounfall behandelt.

## Über

Die Präposition *über* besagt, dass man den Sachverhalt ausführlich darstellt.

> Ich schreibe meinem Freund *über* den Autounfall.

Hierbei darf davon ausgegangen werden, dass der Inhalt des Briefes den Autounfall mehr oder minder ausführlich beschreibt. Der Autounfall mag ein zentraler Teil des Briefes oder vielleicht sogar der ausschließliche Inhalt sein.

## Von

Die Präposition *von* ist der Standardanschluss an *jemandem etwas schreiben.*

> Ich schreibe meinem Freund von dem Autounfall.

Hier ist der Autounfall zwar ebenso wie bei *über* Teil des Briefes aber nicht notwendigerweise zentral. Wir wissen ohne weitere Information nicht, wie ausführlich darüber geschrieben würde; vielleicht beschränkt es sich auch auf:

> Und gestern hatte ich einen Autounfall. Es war aber nur ein Blechschaden.

## Zusammenfassung

Die drei Präpositionen sind *nicht* austauschbar, wobei *von* und *über* inhaltlich deutlich näher zueinander sind und *wegen* einen völlig anderen Sachverhalt beschreibt.

Comment: Dies ist also eine Kontradiktion?: "Bitte schreib **ein wenig** *über* dieses Thema". Es sollte also besser heißen: "Bitte schreib ein wenig von diesem Thema"?

Comment: @Beta Nein. Denn du sollst in dem Fall *über dieses Thema* schreiben (also ein Schriftstück, das sich vorwiegend mit diesem Thema beschäftigt); das, was du schreibst soll aber nur »ein wenig«, also kurz sein. Wenn ich »ein wenig über ein Thema« schreibe, dann zum Beispiel eine kurze fünf-Zeilen-Antwort hier bei Stackexchange ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Ich schreibe meinem Freund wegen des Autounfalls." Ich schreibe meinem Freund weil es ein Autounfall gab, *in Reaktion* (zB Sympathie).

"Ich schreibe meinem Freund über den Autounfall." Ich schreibe meinem Freund um den Autounfall (und nichts ander) *zu diskutieren.*

"Ich schreiben meinem Freund von dem Autounfall." Ich schreibe meinem Freund um den Autounfall (mit anderer Themen) *zu sprechen.*

Sie sind drei verschiedene Grad der "Interesse,"